# Create a button to clear MUI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to create a button to clear MUI autocomplete value and delete `data` from the UI.

using the below code I am able to delete `data` from the UI but `onChange` value still in the autocomplete and I am trying to clear it by clicking `Clear Data & Autocomplete` button

How can I do that?

this image before clicking the button

[image: this image before clicking the button]

this image after clicking the button

[image: this image after clicking the button]

as you can see the `onChange` value still in the autocomplete and I want it to be cleared because I clicked `Clear Data & Autocomplete` button already

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <Autocomplete
        disablePortal
        id="combo-box-demo"
        options={top100Films.map((movie) => movie.label)}
        onChange={(e, val) => setData(val)}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
      />
      <h1>{data}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setData("")}>Clear Data & Autocomplete</button>
    </>
  );
}
const top100Films = [
  { label: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { label: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { label: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { label: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { label: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { label: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { label: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make the `Autocomplete` a controlled input by settings it's value to your `data` state.

```
<>
  <Autocomplete
    disablePortal
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={top100Films.map((movie) => movie.label)}
    onChange={(e, val) => setData(val)}
    // Added value here
    value={data}
    sx={{ width: 300 }}
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
  />
  <h1>{data}</h1>
  <button onClick={() => setData("")}>Clear Data & Autocomplete</button>
</>;
```

CodeSandBox : https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-snyder-1gxnlg?file=/demo.js

Comment: I have always used `value` property inside inputs and didn't fully understand its purpose, but today I understood why we use it and I learned something I will never forget .

Thank you so much Ryan .